# Facebook share, image not displayed

Tags: facebook-graph-api, filepicker.io

Just a question about sharing image on social networks as Fb, Twitter... when they are stored on inkfilepicker.

In my head section, I have put opengraph tags or link but image is never displayed when sharing.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/pZFD49sHQ0yazsb1mTKD">
<link rel="image_src" href="https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/pZFD49sHQ0yazsb1mTKD">
```

Any ideas where it may come from ?

Thanks,

Jul

Comment: Sorry, I know where my mistake comes from, tests are made from a test server with a htaccess authentication security. 401 error put me on the way with this facebook testing page https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Comment: Confirmed and resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src=" image link here " />
```

Please try to write as above .

Comment: I guess I was missing namespace declaration, I try again

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using this Open Graph tags, and they works, i have changed the connection to database in php to the `<header>` section of the page, **without the "og:image:width" and "og:image:height" tags, the first time the article is shared, no image is shown, due to a Facebook cache problem.**

```
<meta property="og:image" content="/path/to/image" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="image_width_in_pixels" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="image-height_in_pixels" />
<meta property="og:url" content="url_being_shared" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:title" content="title_of_article" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description_of_article" />
```

You can find more information about that in:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices/#precaching